# Creating directory from filename then moving file into that directory

Tags: vb.net

I have a situation where I have multiple files named in a YearMonthDate convention format that I would like to move into a directory based on the month then a sub directory based on the date listed in the file name. With help I've arrived at the following:

```
Public Class Form1
    Function MakeDirectoryPath(rootFolder As String, fileName As String) As String
        Dim monthDirectory As String = DateAndTime.MonthName(Asc(fileName(2)) - 96) 
        Dim dayDirectory As String = fileName.Substring(3, 2)                       
        Return IO.Path.Combine(rootFolder, monthDirectory, dayDirectory)            
    End Function

    Sub CreateDirectory(rootSource As String, rootDestination As String)

        For Each s As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(rootSource)                   
            Dim fileName As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(s)                         
            Dim destinationDirectory As String = MakeDirectoryPath(rootDestination, fileName)  

            If Not IO.Directory.Exists(destinationDirectory) Then
                IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationDirectory)
            End If
            **IO.File.Move(s, destinationDirectory)**
        Next

    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        CreateDirectory(".....", "......")   
    End Sub
End Class
```

The Function pulls what I want from the filename and the Sub CreateDirectory creates my month directory and then my sub directory. Issue I'm having is moving the actual files into their respected directories.

Simply dropping
    IO.File.Move(destinationDirectory)
within the For Each loop produces an exception due to the directories already existing and I'm not having any better luck with the IO.File.Copy().

Help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exception do you get with File.Move? Do you really want to move it, or just create a copy?

Comment: io.file.move requires two arguments--source filename and destination filename.  So please put the IO.File.Move line in the code where you want, the way you think it needs to be, and then we'll maybe be able to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Added "IO.File.Move(s, destinationDirectory)" into the code in the original post. Exception I'm getting from it is an System.IO.IOException relating to "Cannot create a file when that file already exists". Most likely because IO.File.Move is trying to recreate the directories. I also wish to move the files but was thinking of using IO.File.Copy and IO.File.Delete as a sloppy way to get around this problem I'm having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx) takes path&filename. In your sample, the destination is a path only, you have to add the filename.

```
IO.File.Move(s, IO.Path.Combine(destinationDirectory, fileName))
```

Comment: Also, I'm not sure it's a good idea to iterate the `GetFiles` directly while moving files out of that directory. I would suggest to iterate on a string array variable that gets it's values from the `GetFiles` method.

Comment: @ZoharPeled GetFiles does return an array. In VB the GetFile would be called once at the beginning of the loop (different from C# which would be called on each loop).

Comment: Well, you've got me there... it's been a long time since my vb.net days... Moved to c#

Comment: Thank you very much the_lotus. Wow, can't believe I couldn't put that together after reading the move API a dozen times.  Program is doing what I want now.